# Get the text between two "-"s for each row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

Can someone please help me with trimming the below sample texts in SQL Server? I am looking to get the data between the two `'-'` (some rows do not have a `'-'`).

```
AB DCE
CM-AB DCE  -228
ABC
CM-AB DCE-214
CJ-ABC-228
```

The output expected is:

```
AB DCE
AB DCE
ABC
AB DCE
ABC
```

I tried:

```
select substring(mycol, 4, charindex('-', mycol, 12) )
```

But the results are not accurate.

Comment: You can use `STRING_SPLIT`. Although trying to find something in the middle of a string suggests there's a serious database design problem. You *can't* use indexes to search in the middle of a string which means the query would have to scan the entire table to find matches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the question has been answered here

https://www.webcodeexpert.com/2016/08/sql-server-query-to-get-string-between.html

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(txt,CHARINDEX('-',txt)+1,
(((LEN(txt))-CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(txt)))-CHARINDEX('-',txt)))
AS Result FROM tab
```

Answer (score 0):

If you gather the position of your first symbol, and the position of your second symbol with `CHARINDEX`, you can extract what's contained inbetween with `SUBSTRING`.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           CHARINDEX('-', txt)                        AS startidx,
           CHARINDEX('-', txt, CHARINDEX('-', txt)+1) AS endidx
    FROM tab
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(txt, 
                 CASE WHEN startidx > 0 THEN startidx+1 ELSE 0 END,
                 CASE WHEN startidx > 0 THEN endidx-startidx-1 ELSE LEN(txt) END) AS txt
FROM cte
```

**Output**:

| txt |
| --- |
| AB DC |
| AB DCE |
| AB |
| AB DCE |
| ABC |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cS0_EGhB).